# Creating temporary SSL certificates for development to be used by X509Certificate2 and mono in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono, x509certificate2

Today I've been struggling with this problem all day long and still got nowhere. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Writing a secure TCP server in C# using Mono in Ubuntu.

For this I need to instantiate a `X509Certificate2` object and give it a certificate file. But as I am still in development phase, things are a little different than production. Links like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx) explain how to do this in Windows for cases like mine. But I'm trying to do this in Ubuntu.

On the other hand there are [resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html#generating-a-csr) explaining how to add a local self-signed root certificate in Ubuntu. But I can not mix these two articles into each other and figure out the way. I mean I tried so many times but each time a new problem rises as there are so many parameters that can go wrong.

To name what exactly I hope to achieve: I need a `X509Certificate2` object which can both decrypt and encrypt so it needs to be given both public and private keys.

Can anyone guide me through?